Deepcheck fails with unknown host exception
Build.yml file there is this deepcheck step
      - name: Depcheck
    uses: dependency-check/Dependency-Check_Action@main
    id: Depcheck
    continue-on-error: true
    env:
      # actions/setup-java@v3 changes JAVA_HOME so it needs to be reset to match the depcheck image
      JAVA_HOME: /opt/jdk
    with:
      project: ${{ inputs.sonar-project-name }}
      path: '.'
      format: 'HTML'

it fails giving the following error.
    Error:  Could not connect to Central search. Analysis failed.
java.io.IOException: Finally failed connecting to Central search. Giving up after 7 tries.
    at org.owasp.dependencycheck.analyzer.CentralAnalyzer.fetchMavenArtifacts(CentralAnalyzer.java:363)
    at org.owasp.dependencycheck.analyzer.CentralAnalyzer.analyzeDependency(CentralAnalyzer.java:228)
    at org.owasp.dependencycheck.analyzer.AbstractAnalyzer.analyze(AbstractAnalyzer.java:131)
    at org.owasp.dependencycheck.AnalysisTask.call(AnalysisTask.java:88)
    at org.owasp.dependencycheck.AnalysisTask.call(AnalysisTask.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: search.maven.org
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:572)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:639)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:533)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:638)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1131)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:142)
    at org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.central.CentralSearch.searchSha1(CentralSearch.java:169)
    at org.owasp.dependencycheck.analyzer.CentralAnalyzer.fetchMavenArtifacts(CentralAnalyzer.java:340)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
[WARN] An error occurred while analyzing '/github/workspace/target/quarkus-app/lib/boot/io.quarkus.quarkus-development-mode-spi-3.8.2.jar' (Central Analyzer).

in my pom.xml have this nexus configured ,files are successfully uploaded there.
   <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>proj-releases</id>
            <url>https://**********************************releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>proj-snapshots</id>
            <url>*******************************************apshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

Upload is successful ,also tried to ping search.maven.org    ,but gives timeout.
